# Why does php mail not fire when called from other function

Tags: php, email

I am wondering why this mail function will not execute when it's inside my funtion which I call when the user submits the form

```
function checkSpam() {
    if (strpos($_POST['strasse'], 'spamexample') !== false)  {
        mail($tofake,$subject,$body,$headers);
        echo "fake";
    }
    else {
        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
        echo "real";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["senden"])) {
    checkSpam ();
}

?>
```

Comment: As soon as I place mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers); outside the function, it will send the mail. If it stays within only the echo part works when I submit my form

Comment: it might because of the variable scopes they are not available inside the function but outside

Comment: so i was right :D

Comment: Well, where do you think `$tofake`,`$subject`,`$body`,`$headers` and `$to` are going to come from, within your function? Remember that variables you declare outside a function are not available inside the function (and vice-versa) - you'd need to pass them in as parameters to the checkSpam() function. If you didn't know that, now would be a really good time to go and research the topic of "variable scope" in PHP. Start by reading the [relevant bit of the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).